# Matplotlib plotting two dataframes in one scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am able to plot two indivdiual scatter plots for df5 and df8 using this but I can't seem to plot them on the same figure.

```
# plot
plt.plot( 'Temperature', 'Moment', data=df5, linestyle='none', marker='o', alpha=0.4, markerfacecolor='lightblue',
         markersize='6')
plt.rcParams["font.family"] ="sans-serif" 
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 10
plt.xlabel('Temperature(K)')
plt.ylabel('DC Moment (emu)')
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(15)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
```

**To plot them on same figure I tried the following but it does not work, it gives a straight line, both the df has same number of rows and columns**

```
x1= df5['Temperature']
y1= df5['Moment']
x2= df8['Temperature']
y2= df8['Moment']

plt.scatter(x1, y1, color= 'g')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, color='b')
```

Comment: This should actually plot both on the same figure. Can you add more info? How does your data look like? Are you doing this in jupyter notebook? how is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the build-in matplotlib-based plotting of pandas right away. The only important note is that you need to tell matplotlib *to which axis* it is supposed to draw the points:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# open figure/axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot // you need to specify the axis
df5.plot(x='Temperature', y='Moment', kind='scatter', ax=ax, c='g')
df8.plot(x='Temperature', y='Moment', kind='scatter', ax=ax, c='b')
```

If you insist on using matplotlib all the way, open a figure with an axis and plot to the same axis:

```py
# open figure/axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax .scatter(x1, y1, color='g')
# use the same axis object to plot the other values
ax .scatter(x2, y2, color='b')
```